# Entrance exam preparation suggestions.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I will be giving my Entrance Exam for (MS in Computer Science) and this is the Syllabus.

Syllabus Screenshot :

[image]

I am worried about the maths and reasoning part. It's not that I have not done it but I am out of practice. And I am worried about the reasoning part too. It is my dream university which I want to get into. So anyhow, I want to score good. Will you guys please suggest me some books for Maths and Reasoning. Good books, so that I can start preparation. The exam is going held in February 2015, so I hardly have much time in my hand. Thank you all.

Comment: A good book that covers a lot of your topics is given by [mary boas bible](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/0471365807?pc_redir=1408077470&robot_redir=1) it covers most if not all the subjects you describe. In addition there are some books in the schuam series, but they are more directed at per subject. Ps re tag as soft question (as I see that as the only reason for a -1) :). Good luck.